# Why is azure cli looking for .docker/config.json inside my go/bin directory when I'm trying to login to azure acr?

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to login to Azure ACR. Docker is working good in my machine. I already used the command `az login` and it went well. Now I'm using the command `az acr login --name myacr`, it's complaining with the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<my_user>\\Development\\go\\bin\\.docker\\config.json'
```

Please help me understand this coz I want to push an image to my ACR

Comment: Are you the owner of the ACR?

Comment: Could you use this command to login it `docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -p myPassword`?

Comment: docker login worked fine, but why is `az acr login --name myacr` not working? And isn't it supposed to look for `.docker/config.json` inside my Home Directory? Not in `go/bin`

Comment: Can you run that command in that path `C:\\Users\\<my_user>\\Development\\go\\bin\\`?

Comment: pardon? hat command? sorry, I'm not that experienced already. Also I tried pushing an image to the ACR and it works fine now, only the `az acr login` command does not work

Comment: Sorry, I mean, could you please re-run that command in that path `C:\Users\<my_user>\Development\go\bin\`?

Comment: same result, "No such file or directory". My `.docker/config.json` resides inside `<HomeDir>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165862/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-johnstephen-19).

Comment: Are you the owner of that resource in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess without further information is that one or more of the environment variables may be set that override the home directory location. Could you please check the values of any of the following environment variables? In Command Prompt enter:

```
echo %HOME%
echo %USERPROFILE%
echo %HOMEPATH%
echo %HOMEDRIVE%
```

For additional help please contact ACR Support (acrsup@microsoft.com) as this is a specific client side issue.

Comment: yeah, %HOME% variable is go/bin